# CSS and Javascript rotate works only once onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, css-transforms, rotatetransform

I am using this to rotate a div `onclick` event:

```
function ghum(){
    document.getElementById("earth").className += " rotate";
}
```

and this to rotate anticlockwise:

```
function revghum(){
    document.getElementById("earth").className += " revrotate";
}
```

but it works once. One more problem is that if I click on the second event before the first then the first event will automatically not working.

I actually want this div to rotate every time on a click.
Here is the example
http://maatren.com/earth/

In rotate and revrotate I am using only the transform and transition to rotate div, and in  id earth I'm using the background image without any transform and transition.

Comment: Once you add the class, the style is applied to the div. If you add the same css class again, the same style applies, it doesn't apply x2. You should use the events to actually change the orientation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery with "addClass" and "removeClass", but not keep adding the class name with "className +=".

API addClass:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

API removeClass:
http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 0):

With js you can use the toggle method on the element such as `.classList.toggle('rotate')`